# Java array initialization

Tags: java, arrays, indexing

Given a bunch of temperatures, I am supposed to put them into an array that sorts them by every 10 degrees. I am pretty confused. I was able to print out all the temperatures from a provided txt file, but now I am not sure how to put them into an array. There should be 11 indexes( <=9, 10-19, 20-29, 30-39, 40-49, 50-59, 60-69, 70-79, 80-89, 90-99, and >=100). I am just really confused on how to use arrays.

Comment: that seems like homework that you are not willing to put some effort in ;)

Comment: The [Java Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) is your friend.

Comment: No no no, there is much more to the program than this, and I can do the rest if I can just figure this part out. I spent 4 hours today trying and I'm hopeless.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use multidimensional array or a hash table that sort temperatures in a range from 1 to 10 and from 10 to 20

Answer (score 0):

Put to the array the upper edges:

```
int[] a = {10, 20, 30, ..., Integer.MAX_INTEGER}
```

It defines intervals 0-9, 10-19, etc.